# Именованный канал по сети без логина и пароля

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pipes

Как создать именованный канал в Windows, чтобы можно было читать из него и записывать данные в него без каких-либо логинов и паролей с компьютеров в локальной сети? Изъяны в безопасности при использовании такого канала меня не волнуют, так как это учебная программа. Хотелось бы обойтись без сложных настроек в ОС. Нужно, чтобы работало хотя бы в Windows XP и 7.

Вот пример, который работает на одном компьютере, но не на нескольких.
Код сервера:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

char msg1[]="Message1";
char msg2[]="Message2";

int main(){ 
    std::string c;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa={0};
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd={0};

    InitializeSecurityDescriptor( 
     &sd,
     SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);

    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl( 
     &sd, 
     TRUE, 
     NULL, 
     FALSE);
    sa.bInheritHandle=false;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor=&sd;
    sa.nLength=sizeof(sa);
    HANDLE ch1=CreateNamedPipe (
        "\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", 
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE| PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        sizeof msg1, 4, 0, &sa
    );
    if(ch1==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        std::cout<<"ch1 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    HANDLE ch2=CreateNamedPipe(
        "\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", 
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE| PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        sizeof msg1, 4, 0, &sa
    );
    if(ch2==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        std::cout<<"ch2 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    ConnectNamedPipe(ch1, 0);
    ConnectNamedPipe(ch2, 0);

    unsigned long foo;
    if(TransactNamedPipe(ch1, msg1, sizeof msg1, &foo, sizeof foo, &foo, 0)==0){
        std::cout<<"transact1 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    if(TransactNamedPipe(ch2, msg2, sizeof msg2, &foo, sizeof foo, &foo, 0)==0){
        std::cout<<"transact2 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout<<"Finished\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Код клиента:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

char msg1[]="Message1\n";
char msg2[]="Message2\n";

int main(){ 
    std::string c;
    std::cout<<"Server name:\n";
    std::string sname;
    std::cin>>sname;
    std::cin.ignore();
    NETRESOURCE nr={0};
    if(sname!="."){
        std::string sname2=std::string("\\\\")+sname;
        nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
            nr.lpRemoteName = &sname2[0];
        DWORD ret=WNetAddConnection2( &nr, "", "", 0);
        if(ret!=NO_ERROR){
            std::cout<<"WNetAddConnection2 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
            std::getline(std::cin, c);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    std::string pname=std::string("\\\\")+sname+std::string("\\pipe\\testpipe");
    HANDLE phandle1=CreateFile (
        pname.c_str(), 
        GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 
        0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,0
    );
    if(phandle1==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        std::cout<<"CreateFile1 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    HANDLE phandle2=CreateFile (
        pname.c_str(), 
        GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 
        0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,0
    );
    if(phandle2==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        std::cout<<"CreateFile2 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    char msg[sizeof(msg1)];
    unsigned long s;
    unsigned long foo=0;
    if(ReadFile(phandle1, &msg, sizeof msg1, &s, 0)==0){
        std::cout<<"ReadFile1 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout<<msg<<"\n";
    if(WriteFile (phandle1, &foo, sizeof foo, &foo, 0)==0){
        std::cout<<"WriteFile1 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    if(ReadFile(phandle2, &msg, sizeof msg1, &s, 0)==0){
        std::cout<<"ReadFile2 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout<<msg<<"\n";
    if(WriteFile (phandle2, &foo, sizeof foo, &foo, 0)==0){
        std::cout<<"WriteFile2 "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, c);
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout<<"Finished\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Конкретная ошибка: 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) при первом вызове `CreateFile` в клиентской программе.

**Обновление**

Я немного разобрался с именованными каналами. Нужно ещё добавить на машине, где запускается сервер, в разделе `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters` в `NullSessionPipes` имя канала. Тогда приведённый выше код работает, если сервер — Win XP, а клиент Win 7. А вот наоборот почему-то работает лишь для чтения (`GENERIC_READ` вместо `GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE` в `CreateFile`), иначе опять ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Я также нашёл [статью про анонимные каналы](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813414/how-to-create-an-anonymous-pipe-that-gives-access-to-everyone) на MSDN. Там куда более сложный пример, но в нём предоставляется только доступ на чтение, а изменить код, чтобы работала запись, мне не удалось. Я установил `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX` вместо `PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND` в `CreateNamedPipe`, `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` вместо `FILE_GENERIC_READ` в `AddAccessAllowedAce`, `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` вместо `GENERIC_READ` в `CreateFile`, но ошибка 5 также возникает, если сервер Win 7.

Вот что в реестре Windows 7 (может где-то там ошибка?) Значение NullSessionPipes содержит строки "testpipe" и "AnonymousPipe".

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
  73,00,72,00,76,00,73,00,76,00,63,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ServiceDllUnloadOnStop"=dword:00000001
"EnableAuthenticateUserSharing"=dword:00000001
"NullSessionPipes"=hex(7):74,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,70,00,69,00,70,00,65,00,00,\
  00,41,00,6e,00,6f,00,6e,00,79,00,6d,00,6f,00,75,00,73,00,50,00,69,00,70,00,\
  65,00,00,00,00,00
"autodisconnect"=dword:0000000f
"enableforcedlogoff"=dword:00000001
"enablesecuritysignature"=dword:00000000
"requiresecuritysignature"=dword:00000000
"restrictnullsessaccess"=dword:00000000
"Lmannounce"=dword:00000000
"Size"=dword:00000001
"AdjustedNullSessionPipes"=dword:00000003
"Guid"=hex:eb,c5,75,fd,46,51,ce,4c,8f,64,a9,70,12,f6,05,6e
```

Подскажите, как нужно правильно создавать анонимный именованный канал?

**Обновление 2**

Если включить настройку «Сетевой доступ: разрешать применение разрешений "Для всех" к анонимным пользователям» или добавить разрешение «Имитация клиента после проверки подлинности» для группы АНОНИМНЫЙ ВХОД, то и мой пример, и пример MSDN работают без ошибок. Только непонятно, почему — ведь функции олицетворения нигде не вызываются.

**Обновление 3**

Наконец, нашёл статьи, в которых объясняется в чём дело: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nettracer/2010/07/23/why-does-anonymous-pipe-access-fail-on-windows-vista-2008-windows-7-or-windows-2008-r2/, http://blog.m-ri.de/index.php/2009/12/08/windows-integrity-control-schreibzugriff-auf-eine-named-pipe-eines-services-ueber-anonymen-zugriff-auf-vista-windows-2008-server-und-windows-7/ (на немецком, можно читать в переводе на английский) Приведённый в последней статье пример работает, не выдавая ошибки без упомянутых выше настроек! (Нужно только добавить имя канала в `NullSessionPipes`)

Так как я все равно объявил конкурс и тема практически нигде не освещена, хорошо бы, чтобы кто-нибудь написал подробный ответ на основе перечисленных статей.

Comment: "Вот оно чё, Михалыч!" (c) @Im ieee, good find! Прекрасно заработало и без доступа к IPC$ (только на XP пришлось firewall остановить; еще, пишут, можно разрешить порт 445)
Ответ нужно писать Вам самому, так как это Ваша находка (отличная, и весьма полезная находка!); лично я считаю неэтичным пользоваться чужим ответом (а вот поблагодарить за него - дело чести).

Comment: @SeNS дело в том, что я не могу отметить «наградой» собственный ответ. Но если никто не ответит, тогда, конечно, это сделаю я. А с доступом к IPC$ — я так понимаю, его включает та же настройка, что повышает Integrity Level клиента.

Comment: >>Но если никто не ответит, тогда, конечно, это сделаю я.
Имеете полнейшее и неотъемлемое право, поскольку ответ нашли вы сами! 
Касательно доступа к IPC$: нет, правильный код (который привел немец) всего лишь добавляет имя канала в NullSessionPipes в реестре. Это не дает доступа к IPC$. Т.е. гитхабовский код, который я приводил, работает только в том случае, если анонимный доступ к IPC$ разрешен (что есть потенциальная "дырка" в security), код немца работает без этого (в принципе то, что вы и хотели). Может, когда-нибудь и я воспользуюсь этим триком.

Comment: То-бишь, если исправить в гитхабовском коде server.cpp вот так:

 `//Define SDDL for the security descriptor
 PCWSTR szSDDL = L"D:"  //Discretionary ACL
//  L"(A;OICI;GA;;;AN)"
//  L"(A;OICI;GA;;;AU)"  //allow read/write to authenticated users
//  L"(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)"  //allow full control to administrators
//  ;
  L"("(A;;GA;;;"))"
  L"(A;;GWGR;;;AN)"
  L"(A;;GWGR;;;WD)";`

, то все заработает.

P.S. Сорри, никак не получается отформатировать код в дурацких комментариях!

Answer (score 5):

Вот [рабочий пример](https://github.com/adrianm32/NamedPipes) named pipes. С реестром мудрить не нужно; единственно, на клиенте в исходном коде нужно заменить (чтобы заработало на двух разных PC в сети, а не на одной машине) `#define SERVER_NAME L"YOUR_REAL_SERVER_NAME"` (т.е. на реальное windows имя компьютера, где будет запущен сервер),  а на сервере можно оставить `#define SERVER_NAME L"."`

**[UPDATE]** Согласно ответу, [найденному](http://blog.m-ri.de/index.php/2009/12/08/windows-integrity-control-schreibzugriff-auf-eine-named-pipe-eines-services-ueber-anonymen-zugriff-auf-vista-windows-2008-server-und-windows-7/) @Im ieee , в [примере с GitHub](https://github.com/adrianm32/NamedPipes)-а нужно заменить строки 199-201 на:

```
L"(A;OICI;GA;;;AN)"    // allow full control to anonymous
L"(A;OICI;GRGW;;;AU)"  // allow read/write to authenticated users
L"(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)"    // allow full control to administrators
;
```

а на клиенте добавить такие строки перед попыткой открыть анонимный именованный канал:

```
NETRESOURCE nr;
ZeroMemory( &nr, sizeof(nr) );
nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
nr.lpRemoteName = FULL_SERVER_NAME;

dwError = WNetAddConnection2( &nr, L"", L"", 0);
if( dwError != ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    wprintf_s(L"WNetAddConnection2 fails");
    goto Cleanup;
}
```

после чего и это решение будет работать (с учетом, что имя тестовой named pipe, SamplePipe, добавлено в переменную реестра **SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\NullSessionPipes**

Вот полный код решения: **client.cpp**

```
#pragma region Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma endregion

#define SERVER_NAME L"VIRTUAL-XP"  // change to your server name!
#define FULL_SERVER_NAME L"\\\\" SERVER_NAME
#define PIPE_NAME L"SamplePipe"
#define FULL_PIPE_NAME FULL_SERVER_NAME L"\\pipe\\" PIPE_NAME

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

#define REQUEST_MESSAGE L"Default request from client"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    HANDLE hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    NETRESOURCE nr;
    ZeroMemory( &nr, sizeof(nr) );
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
    nr.lpRemoteName = FULL_SERVER_NAME;

    // These lines make client work with any server (including XP)
    // even if you not in domain or logged to the server 
    // But don't forget to ass named pipe name to the registry on server!
    dwError = WNetAddConnection2( &nr, L"", L"", 0);
    if( dwError != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        wprintf_s(L"WNetAddConnection2 fails");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    while (TRUE)
    {
        hPipe = CreateFile(
            FULL_PIPE_NAME,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0, // no sharing
            nullptr, //default security attributes
            OPEN_EXISTING, //open existing pipe
            SECURITY_ANONYMOUS,  //default attributes
            nullptr // no template file
            );

        if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"The named pipe %s is now connected. \n", FULL_PIPE_NAME);
            break;
        }

        dwError = GetLastError();

        if( dwError == ERROR_PIPE_BUSY ) 
        {
            //all pipe instances are busy so wait for 5 secs
            if (!WaitNamedPipe(FULL_PIPE_NAME, 5000))
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
                wprintf_s(L"Could not open named pipe. 5 sec timeout expired \n");
                goto Cleanup;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            wprintf_s(L"Unable to open named pipe with error %08lx \n", dwError);
            goto Cleanup;
        }
    }


    // Set the read mode and blocking mode of the named pipe. Here , we set data to be read from the pipe as a stream of messages.
    DWORD dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE;
    if (!SetNamedPipeHandleState(hPipe, &dwMode, nullptr, nullptr))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        wprintf_s(L"SetNamedPipeHandleState failed with error %08lx \n", dwError);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //Send request from client to server
    wchar_t chRequest[] = REQUEST_MESSAGE;
    DWORD cbRequest, cbWritten;

    cbRequest = sizeof(chRequest);

    if (!WriteFile(hPipe, chRequest, cbRequest, &cbWritten, nullptr))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        wprintf_s(L"WriteFile failed with error message %08lx \n", dwError);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"Sent %ld bytes to server: %s \n", cbWritten, chRequest);

    // Receive a response from the server
    BOOL fFinishRead = TRUE;


    do
    {
       wchar_t chResponse[BUFFER_SIZE];
        DWORD cbResponse, cbRead;

        cbResponse = sizeof(chResponse);

        fFinishRead = ReadFile(hPipe, chResponse, cbResponse, &cbRead,              nullptr);

        dwError = GetLastError();

        if (!fFinishRead && ERROR_MORE_DATA != dwError)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"Readfile from pipe %s failed with error %08lx \n", FULL_PIPE_NAME, dwError);
            break;
        }

        wprintf(L"Receive %ld bytes fom server : %s \n", cbRead, chResponse);

    } while (!fFinishRead);

Cleanup:
    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hPipe);
        hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

return dwError;
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
/***************************************

PIPE_ACCESS_IMBOUND:
Client (Generic_Write)  ->  Server( Generic_Read)

PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND:
Server (Generic_Write) -> Client (Generic_Read)

PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX:
Client (Generic_Read or Generic_Write or Both) <--> Server (Generic_Read and Generic_Write)

*******************************************/

#pragma region Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>    //security descriptor description language
#pragma endregion


#define SERVER_NAME     L"."
#define PIPE_NAME   L"SamplePipe"
#define FULL_PIPE_NAME  L"\\\\" SERVER_NAME L"\\pipe\\" PIPE_NAME     //concatenation done by compiler

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024


#define RESPONSE_MESSAGE L"Default response from server"


//Forward declarations of methods so that they can be used in main method. These will be defined later.
BOOL CreatePipeSecurity(PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *);
void FreePipeSecurity(PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES );


int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    DWORD dwError = ERROR_SUCCESS;  //error code definitions in winerr.h for windows apis
    PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pSA = nullptr;
    HANDLE hNamedPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;   //handleapi.h

    // Prepare the security attributes (the lpSecurityAttributes parameter in 
    // CreateNamedPipe) for the pipe. This is optional. If the 
    // lpSecurityAttributes parameter of CreateNamedPipe is NULL, the named 
    // pipe gets a default security descriptor and the handle cannot be 
    // inherited. The ACLs in the default security descriptor of a pipe grant 
    // full control to the LocalSystem account, (elevated) administrators, 
    // and the creator owner. They also give only read access to members of 
    // the Everyone group and the anonymous account. However, if you want to 
    // customize the security permission of the pipe, (e.g. to allow 
    // Authenticated Users to read from and write to the pipe), you need to 
    // create a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure.
    if (!CreatePipeSecurity(&pSA))   //passing by ref so that the actual pointer value is updated.
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();  //errohandlingapi.h
        wprintf_s(L"CreatePipeSecurity failed with error 0x%08lx\n", dwError); // printf format %[parameter][flags][width][.precision][length]type
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //Create Named pipe
    hNamedPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        FULL_PIPE_NAME,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,  //open mode
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |
            PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, //max intances
        BUFFER_SIZE, //output buffer size
        BUFFER_SIZE, // input buffer size
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, //time out interval
        pSA
        );

    if (hNamedPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        wprintf_s(L"CreateNamedPipe failed with error %08lx\n", dwError);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"The named pipe (%s) has been successfully created. \n", FULL_PIPE_NAME);

    //wait for the client to connect.
    wprintf_s(L"Waiting for the client to connect. \n");

    // Blocking call on server.
    //ConnectNamedPipe Enables a named pipe server process to wait for a client process to connect to an instance of a named pipe. A client process connects by calling either the CreateFile or CallNamedPipe function.
    if (!ConnectNamedPipe(hNamedPipe, nullptr))   //namedpipeapi.h
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"ConnectNamedPipe failed with error %08lx \n", dwError);
            goto Cleanup;
        }
    }

    wprintf(L"Client is connected.\n");

    //Receive request from client.

    BOOL fFinishedRead = FALSE;

    do
    {
        wchar_t chRequest[BUFFER_SIZE];
        DWORD cbRequest, cbRead;
        cbRequest = sizeof(chRequest);

        //another blocking call.
        fFinishedRead = ReadFile(    //fileapi.h
            hNamedPipe,  //file handle which is the named pipe handle
            chRequest, //buffer
            cbRequest, // no. of bytes to read
            &cbRead, // no. of bytes read  , pass by ref so that the callee can update the value.
            nullptr
            );

        dwError = GetLastError();
        if (!fFinishedRead && dwError != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"ReadFile failed with error %08lx \n", dwError);
            goto Cleanup;
        }

        wprintf_s(L"Received %ld bytes from client: %s \n", cbRead, chRequest);

    } while (!fFinishedRead); //repeat loop if ERROR_MORE_DATA.


    //send a response from server to client.

    wchar_t chResponse[] = RESPONSE_MESSAGE;
    DWORD cbResponse, cbWritten;
    cbResponse = sizeof(chResponse);

    //another blocking call.
    if (!WriteFile(
        hNamedPipe,
        chResponse,
        cbResponse,
        &cbWritten,
        nullptr
        ))

    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        wprintf_s(L"WriteFile failed with error %08lx \n", dwError);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"Sent %ld bytes to client: %s \n", cbWritten, chResponse);

    //Flush the pipe to allow the client to read the pipe's contents before disconnecting.
    FlushFileBuffers(hNamedPipe);
    DisconnectNamedPipe(hNamedPipe);

Cleanup:
    if (!pSA)
    {
        FreePipeSecurity(pSA);
        pSA = nullptr;  //always null after releasing.
    }

    if (hNamedPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hNamedPipe);
        hNamedPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return dwError;
}

//
//   FUNCTION: CreatePipeSecurity(PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *)
//
//   PURPOSE: The CreatePipeSecurity function creates and initializes a new 
//   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure to allow Authenticated Users read and 
//   write access to a pipe, and to allow the Administrators group full 
//   access to the pipe.
//
//   PARAMETERS:
//   * ppSa - output a pointer to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure that allows 
//     Authenticated Users read and write access to a pipe, and allows the 
//     Administrators group full access to the pipe. The structure must be 
//     freed by calling FreePipeSecurity.
BOOL CreatePipeSecurity(PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *ppSA)
{
    BOOL fSucceeded = TRUE;
    DWORD dwError = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = nullptr;
    PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pSA = nullptr;

    //Define SDDL for the security descriptor
    PCWSTR szSDDL = L"D:"  //Discretionary ACL
        L"(A;OICI;GA;;;AN)"  //allow full control to anonymous
        L"(A;OICI;GRGW;;;AU)"  //allow read/write to authenticated users
        L"(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)"  //allow full control to administrators
        ;

    if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(szSDDL, SDDL_REVISION_1, &pSD, nullptr))
    {
        fSucceeded = FALSE;
        dwError = GetLastError();
        goto Cleanup;

    }

    //allocate memory for security attributes
    pSA = (PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(*pSA));  //minwinbase.h for LPTR
    if (pSA == nullptr)
    {
        fSucceeded = FALSE;
        dwError = GetLastError();
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    pSA->nLength = sizeof(*pSA);  //sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)
    pSA->lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
    pSA->bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    *ppSA = pSA;

Cleanup:
    if (!fSucceeded)
    {
        if (pSD)
        {
            LocalFree(pSD);   //winbase.h
            pSD = nullptr;
        }

        if (pSA)
        {
            LocalFree(pSA);
            pSA = nullptr;
        }

        SetLastError(dwError);
    }

    return fSucceeded;
}


void FreePipeSecurity(PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pSA)
{
    if (pSA)
    {
        if (pSA->lpSecurityDescriptor)
        {
            LocalFree(pSA->lpSecurityDescriptor);  //clear its contents first.

        }
        LocalFree(pSA);  //then clear itself.

    }
}
```

P.S. Если будете собирать в **Release** конфигурации, не забудьте указать в опциях препроцессора _UNICODE;UNICODE;

Comment: Да, проверял на Win10 + Win7.

Comment: Еще проверил между XP и 10, все работает.
**Важное примечание:** клиент должен иметь доступ к IPC$ сервера (хоть какой-то), иначе клиент будет вылетать с ошибкой 0x0000052e, что означает: _"Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. Access to IPC$ is denied. (Not the authentication agent's pipe in particular, but the IPC resource itself.) This is expected if your client is trying to connect to a server that is not in the client's Windows domain."_

Comment: Спасибо, что снова помогаете! К сожалению, у меня этот код также выдаёт ошибку 5 в `CreateFile` на клиенте, и когда сервер 7, а клиент XP, и когда наоборот. Думаю, из-за того, что разрешения даются группе «Прошедшие проверку», а она не включает анонимов. Вообще я уже почти разобрался (см. Обновление 2 в вопросе), только непонятно, почему нужно давать такое странное разрешение.

Comment: Попробовал еще разок (сервер на XP, клиент на 10-ке), все работает при условии, что разрешен доступ к IPC$. К сожалению, не могу проверить на сети с доменом (только в одноранговой).
Как я понимаю, без возможности анонимного доступа к серверу, не будет и доступа к named pipes. Т.е. проблема не в коде (Вашем, с MSDN или с github-а), а в настройках Windows.

Comment: Кстати, такая ошибка, как у Вас (0x00000005, access denied) мне ни разу не встречалась. Еще интересно: почему вы используете XP в работе/обучении? Это реальная необходимость, или просто "под руку попалось"? XP уже устарела, и весьма сильно отличается (по внутреннему устройству) от современных "операционок".

Comment: У меня тоже сеть с рабочей группой. Подозреваю, что как раз нету анонимного доступа к серверу на Windows 7, так как с другого компьютера не получается посмотреть все расшаренные директории через проводник. С другой стороны, настройка «Запретить анонимный доступ к именованным каналам и общим папкам» отключена. Приходится делать программы под XP из-за учебных требований.

Comment: Рад, что вы всё-таки решили написать ответ! В первой добавленной строке нужно также указать SID пользователя. И без самого главного: строки c "S-1-16-0" код также не будет работать, если сервер Win7. Ещё неплохо бы привести содержимое cpp файлов с Github полностью (так принято на SO, да и репозиторий могут удалить) и написать объяснение (из первой статьи, на technet.microsoft.com).

Comment: Будет работать! :) Как оказалось, "скрипач не нужен"; трик кроется в маленькой строчке `WNetAddConnection2( &nr, L"", L"", 0);` (как я раньше и писал). OK, подредактирую ответ, а Вы проверьте у себя. Я убрал манипуляции с реестром (они работают только под локальным admin-ом, и, теоретически, есть security flaw).

Comment: Проверял: сервер на XP (в реестре прописано имя канала), клиент на Windows 10. Обратно не проверил, но, думаю, должно работать. Т.е. резюмируя: начальное решение, предложенное мной (код с github-а) работоспособно на всех OS, считая от XP (нет времени проверить на более младших версиях Windows). Доступ к IPC$ - необходимое условие (есть у компьютеров в домене), достигается вызовом WNetAddConnection2 на клиенте.

Comment: Уважаемый @Im ieee , проверьте, пожалуйста, код из ответа (мной чуток модифицированный) на Windows 7.

Comment: Извините, что не сразу ответил — провайдер отключил интернет. Мне кажется, у нас какое-то взаимонепонимание. Если сервер на XP, то работает даже самый первый пример из моего вопроса (если имя канала есть в `NullSessionPipes`). Вызов `WNetAddConnection2` немецкий автор, видимо, взял из примера MSDN, который, как и ваш текущий пример, не работают, если сервер Win7. Чтобы ваш пример  заработал, нужно добавить в дескриптор `L"S:(ML;;NW;;;S-1-16-0)"`.

Comment: Между прочим, всё это написано в статьях! Вот что немец пишет про пример от MSDN (в переводе): «This sample is nice for all the XP and Windows 2003 servers use. And interestingly, it also works on Windows Vista, Windows 7 or Windows Server of 2008. But only because this example uses the pipe read only. ... It does not work when the server runs on Vista, Windows 7, or Server 2008 AND the pipe is opened for reading and writing. ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5) is what the client gets when the pipe is to be read and write open».

Comment: "Все дело в том, что у меня велосипеда не было" (с), то бишь есть образ XP для Hyper-V, и сеть с Win10 PC. Поставлю Win7 (благо, MSDN-овская подписка дает возможность), проверю и отредактирую ответ. Спасибо за замечание!